# AS3 - Getting the mouse targets children one level deep

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I want to find only the first level of children. Right now I'm using `e.target.name` but this is also catching those targets children. How would I prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see three possibilities:

- Set all of your one level children as mouseChildren=false.
- Link the events directly to the children and use currentTarget.
- Traverse the target's hierarchy until you find the right parent:

something like this:

```
var clip:DisplayObject=e.target;
while(clip.parent!=e.currentTarget) {
    clip=clip.parent;
}
```

Comment: I thought there might be a better way without having to set each of the children you don't want accessed individually, but this works with me. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Setting `mouseChildren = false;` on any [DisplayObjectContainer](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#mouseChildren) will disable mouse events on all its children.